# Select a file that was created the last minute

Tags: php

Do you know if there is a function in php where it can find all the files in a given directory, that were created the last 1 minute (or in any case at a specified time?).
For example, to select all the txt files that were created the last 10 minutes in a directory..

I hope it's clear what I mean!

Thanx
D.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Why do people want a ready made function for everything nowadays?

Comment: @DesertIce: maybe it's because php standard lib seem to have a function to everything imaginable :P

Comment: Well, better to ask if there is something and if not I can try to make something..

Comment: @thescientist correct me if i am wrong, DRY talks about how to prevent code repetition to keep code "modularised". It does not mean you have to use whatever code is present before

Comment: but why rewrite what has already been written?

Answer (score 2):

There is no creation time as such, only modified-time, which will work reliably across operating systems.

> The filectime() and filemtime() filesystem functions in PHP will allow
> you to check and see when a file has last been changed.
>
> It will return
> a timestamp holding the value of the time the file was last altered

---

You could iterate through the files in the folder, while checking **[`filemtime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php)**.
Something like,

```
foreach (glob("*.txt") as $filename) {
    echo filemtime($filename); //echoes timestamp
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get all files in directory, loop them through and apply [filetime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) function to see when they were created/modified. Copy them to another array and do with them what you please.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
$it = new GlobIterator(__DIR__ . "/*.txt");
$last10mis = 600;
$list = array();
foreach ( $it as $file )
    (time() - $file->getMTime()) <= $last10mis and $list[] = strval($file);

var_dump($list); // all txt files modified in the last 10mins
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in PHP called filemtime that will return the modified time in a UNIX timestamp.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php

from there, and in the example ont that page, it should be fairly straightforward to apply to your needs.